# How to avoid the error 404 (Not found) using pandas read_html in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to obtain the market capitalization of the AVY stock through Yahoo Finance using the function read_html() of pandas.
I am finding problems with some stock symbols but not with others.
For example, if I use the below code, I can get the Market Value of the stock AAPL correctly:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APPL')
cap = df[1][1].iloc[0]
cap
```

Output = '3.03T'

However, I get an error message (404) if I try to obtain the market capitalization of AVY using the read_html() function.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AVY')
cap = df[1][1].iloc[0]
cap
```

If I try to open the hyperlink ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AVY') in my browser works correctly. Is there any solution to avoid this error with the function read_html()?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting a [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) in the `storage_options` of [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) :

```
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)"
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

def fn(sym: str, metric: str = "Market Cap") -> str:
    base_url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}"

    _, rtable = pd.read_html(base_url.format(sym), storage_options=HEADERS)

    return rtable.set_index(0).at[metric, 1]
```

Output :

```
fn("AAPL") # 3.03T
fn("AVY")  # 16.195B
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using pd.read_html() but that inherently assumes the website is pure html, while this website is dynamically rendering many things and therefore uses javascript. That is why it will load in your browser, but pandas is unable to comprehend the javascript because that function only works for html.

If you try to load a simpler website with the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_html('https://www.berkshirehathaway.com/')
```

It will function without a 404 error, though I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the rest of your code, so no promises on that functioning right.

As for how you would gather data from this Javascript website, of course it depends on your use case, but consider using Selenium, which is a very powerful web scraping tool and relatively easy to use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sam. I have re-written my question. Basically, I need to get the market capitalization of the stock AVY using the read_html function of pandas.

Comment: Oh, interesting that some stocks work while others don’t. I’ll look more into this soon